# Is autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity present in this time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, garch

I'm not sure about the presence of a GARCH effect in this first differenced series. What do you suggest? I've fitted an ARIMA(0,1,0), so the original series is a random walk. I'm working with eurusd exchange rates.

[image]

Here you can found the initial plots https://ibb.co/m80N8H                                    and here the squadre residuals of ARIMA(0,1,0) plus Mcleod Li test.           https://ibb.co/dOgdbS                                        . I've tried also  an ARIMA(3,1,0) but it seems the original series  is a random walk.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. But why don't you run an ARCH-LM test which is specifically suited for identifying presence of ARCH effects?

Comment: I've add other plots above. However, I ve tried the test but I have problem to interpret it. The test must be run on the differenced series or on its residuals

Comment: You run the test directly on the data you are examining. If you care about the original series, run it on the original series. If you care about residuals, run it on residuals. The plots in the second link indicate no ARCH patterns.

Comment: I never understood this aspect. Summing up, there is no serial correlation in my squared residuals, so there is no Arch effect. But there is no arch effect in the residuals or in the differenced time series? What's the procedure that i have to follow?  1. I fitted an ARIMA(0,1,0) because data seems to be a random walk   2. Squared residuals have no correlation so no arch effect. What s the next step? Thanks very much

Comment: Next step? If there are no GARCH effects, then there is no need for a GARCH model. More precisely, there is no need to add a GARCH-type conditional variance equation to your current model. Keep the model you have now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think is reasonable to say that considering the simil value of AIC, it doesn't make sense to apply an ARIMA(3,1,0), so we keep the ARIMA(0,1,0)? and Last question, is it useful to analize if the time series or the residuals are normally distributed? The fact that residuals might follow a normal distribution change something? Thanks

Comment: If AIC values are similar then the simpler model is not the better model. Similar AIC values suggest models are about equally good. Regarding normality, it depends on what you are after. If you want to forecast, knowing the residual distribution is relevant. If you want to get maximum likelihood estimates of your model, this is also relevant. (Besides, I personally have doubts about the quality of the answer you have accepted.)

Comment: Looks like you are good to go. That is, you have a model that seems adequate (no ARCH patterns in residuals, normal residuals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the residuals plotting there seems to be a pattern. Have you tried higher order of AR and MA? A first glance for Arch effect is testing non correlation over squared residuals (ljung-box)

Comment: I put above other plots. The squared residuals seems to go well, do you think so?

Comment: What do you mean in your second sentence?